Collision detection with CapsuleCast
I'm attempting to detect when a gameObject with a Capsule Collider and RigidBody attached it lands on the floor, which is a Mesh with a Mesh Collider attached it to it. Adding a tag to the Floor causes collision issues as other materials comprise the Mesh. The Physics.CapsuleCast seems like the best route, but I'm sure how the call should be made?
Help is appreciated.

"Adding a tag to the floor causes collision issues as other materials comprise the mesh" does not make sense to me as currently written. Can you edit your post to explain this in more detail? Try walking us through the steps to create a small sample scene that reproduces the problem you're experiencing.

The mesh is comprised of the floor, walls and windows, i.e. other materials. So, the floor is combined into one (1) renderer. So, applying the Tag will apply to the other materials in the renderer, as well. In addition, the game object is cylinder tossed on the floor by a characterr.

In my opinion, finding tags is a very slow way to access labelled objects. There is usually a better way.

How are you hoping to distinguish the floor with a capsule cast? It would have the same tag or layer restrictions as the regular collision event you've tried, no? Try editing your question to clarify the exact problem you're having.
